# What is the most precise antonym of "talent"?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

Where "talent" here refers to a personal quality of "from birth, being able to do a specific skill well", what is the precise opposite? I.e. what word means on innate inability? Just as an example, someone who has absolute pitch can readily detect (even name) a note, so they would be talented in the skill of transcribing notes. Someone who is born tone deaf, however, has an innate inability to do this skill.

In searching the dictionary, I found several suggested antonyms, however, when presented alone (without the word "talent" given), readers will not recognize the precise meaning. E.g. when readers see "weakness", they will not immediately think of some "innate inability", nor will they imagine some talents that someone might be poor at.

What is the most precise antonym of "talent"?

Comment: Talentless? Untalented? -- This is actually a really good question.

Comment: and a tortuous one.

Comment: congenital ineptitude or innate ineptitude

Comment: Perfect pitch is learned.

Comment: Perhaps inept or unskillful or amateurish?

Answer (score 8):

An ***inaptitude***, an aptitude being a kind of natural ability to do well.

Answer (score 1):

Manqué: [used to describe what a person could or should have been but never was :  short of or frustrated in the fulfillment of one's aspirations or talents —used postpositively](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/manqu%C3%A9)